What are the semantics of git rev-list --objects with commit ranges?
Suppose I run the following command in a git repo:
git rev-list --objects HEAD^..HEAD

This command gives me only objects that are referenced by HEAD and not referenced by HEAD^.
However, if there is an object that is referenced by HEAD^^ and also by HEAD, but not by HEAD^, will that object appear in the output?
Based on experimentation, it looks like the answer is yes.
However, the documentation does not appear to specify the intent, so I am not sure if my experimental results are accidental or not.

Update on my current understanding to clarify the question:

I understand that <old>..<new> is equivalent to ^<old> <new>, which means to take all commits that are reachable from <new> but not reachable from <old>.
(Implementation A1) Philosophically, if we were to expand this notion literally to "trees and blobs referenced by commits", then the "semantically correct" behavior for git rev-list --objects ^<old> <new> is to "find all objects (commits, trees and blobs)  that are reachable from <new> which are not reachable from <old>.
Taking this literally, that would imply that a blob X with the following properties should NOT show up in git rev-list --objects HEAD^..HEAD, because the full set of objects reachable from HEAD^ includes blob X.

referenced by the tree owned by HEAD^^
referenced by the tree owned by HEAD
not directly referenced by the tree owned by HEAD^


However, my experiments indicate that blob X does show up in the output of git rev-list --objects HEAD^..HEAD, which implies the following alternative implementation (Call it A2):

Take all the objects referenced by the commits in the range <old>..<new>.
Remove ONLY the objects referenced by the commit <old> and NOT all of its ancestors and return this set.



Thus, my question can be rephrased as: Is the behavior of git rev-list --objects <old>..<new> equivalent to A1, A2, or something else entirely that sometimes behaves like A1 and sometimes like A2?

HEAD^^ is the first parent of HEAD^. How could it be that a commit is referenced by HEAD^^ but not by HEAD^?

@ElpieKay I wondered too. It seems like the --objects option switches the command behaviour from commit traversal to object traversal, which could mean that it doesn't explore ancestry of given commits.

Hint: how many commits are listed in git rev-list HEAD^..HEAD? The docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_dotted_range_notations

@phd I'm aware of what the dotted range notation means for commits. Will try to clarify my point of confusion by updating the question.

@ElpieKay, I'm referring to trees and blobs, not commits.

@phd I updated the question to try to elaborate a bit more on what I'm asking.
tl;dr experiments indicate that trees and blobs in the commit range output only exclude the negated commit's direct tree, rather than objects all of its ancestors as well. My question is whether this experiment is an isolated data point or generally true.

The docs explains: "send me all object IDs which I need to download if I have the commit object HEAD^ but not HEAD".

I guess taking that literally, having the commit object HEAD^ does NOT mean having all the ancestors of HEAD^ as well, because it is assuming that we might be dealing with a shallow clone?
The docs are not explicit about whether ancestors of HEAD^ are implied, so I guess it is implied that they are not included.

My guess is that shallow clones are ignored, and in a full clone all ancestors are reachable from HEAD^ so they're not included.

My experiment was done in a full clone though, and I found that blob X is still included even though blob X is referenced by HEAD^^, which implies that it is only excluding objects reachable from the tree of <old> (HEAD^ in this case) and not its ancestors.

There are two reads on this, yes, but one is much more useful in practice.
The idea is to efficiently find objects that need to be sent for  a fetch or push, which means trading off the cost of the exhaustive search, that's done every time, with the cost of sometimes (very rarely, in practice) sending already-possessed objects.
It's easiest to see if you say git rev-list --boundary @^..: rev-list stops looking when it reaches (has identified) the boundary commmits, whether or not it's also doing --objects processing.
Both ways have costs. Both ways achieve the same result. The cheaper-overall way is also safer, because the other repo might be shallow and not actually have all the history you just checked. Best to just look at what the other repo told you it has, the fetch/push boundary markers it provided.
edit: some quick checks says --objects doesn't presume possession of any objects other than those in explicitly-listed boundary commits. Which, again, only makes good sense from a safety standpoint, the remote didn't say they have the deeper history, don't rely on them to have it.

I mostly asked this question because I was wondering whether it's reasonable to rely on this behavior. This answer implies there are good reasons for this behavior to continue working as is in the future.

Another good reason: rev-list is a core command, "plumbing", and Git explicitly guarantees the behavior of those commands will not change in any backward-incompatible way.
